# Wordpress 410 RewriteRule in htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can't seem to get a 410 response from my wordpress install. I keep getting a 404 instead. What am I doing wrong? I've searched quite a few posts and all seem to point to the same code or that there Needs to be an `ErrorDocument 410 default` due to a cPanel bug.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#### 410 responses ####
RewriteRule ^test/?$ [G,L]
#### end 410 responses ####

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

ErrorDocument 410 default
```

Also tried this as recommended in the comments without success:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#### 410 responses ####
RewriteRule ^test/?$ [R=410,L]
#### end 410 responses ####

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: It does not. I'm using Chrome's Developer Tools.

Comment: I originally had it directly after the `RewriteBase /` with the same results. I moved it below the request_filename lines based on some other posts to see if it mattered. I know order matters, but I will admit to being green here.

Comment: I tried that before I posted the last comment. Still no dice unfortunately. I'll add it above to show the code to make sure I'm following your direction properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all you should need:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^test/?$ - [R=410,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The main issue I saw with your code was that it was missing the dash `-` to define what to take action on and the place it was early on your previously posted `.htaccess`.

Comment: That did it. The dash. Dang. So simple. Also works with [G,L]. It was just that dash. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Veo I just prefer to use the status code so I know for sure what its doing as there are so many flags with single letters and glad it worked for you :)